# Software Center duplicate apps

Tags: software-center, duplicate

I'm wondering why are there duplicates for some apps on Software Center (20.04)? For instance, there are 2 KeepassXC, 2 Firefox, 2 ImageMagick, 2 Thunderbird, etc. Are they different somehow? Why does this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are seeing are (say for KeepassXC as an example):

1. is the ubuntu packaged version where the source will be listed (in my case running Ubuntu 20.10) as `ubuntu-groovy-universe` and the current packaged version is `2.6.1`. Installing this will be the same as running `sudo apt-get install keepassc`
2. is the snap version where the source will be listed (in my case) as `snapcraft.io` and the current version is `2.6.3`. Installing this will be the same as running `snap install keepassxc`

I think this is one of the letdowns of modern Ubuntu where packages vs. snaps are very confusing to some users (and I include myself in that).

I think back in the day the `Ubuntu Software` listed packages, then at some point a `Snap Store` app was automatically installed (you may see it under `Installed` apps), but you can't seem to run it or find it for whatever reason, so I guess maybe it's merged with the `Ubuntu Software` GUI (as both snaps and packages show there) but who knows, I certainly don't! :-)

If someone has a good resource on the whole snaps/packages and `Ubuntu Software` thing please link to it.

Comment: It makes sense now, though it's still confusing, wish it would be unified somehow.